# Use multiple combo boxes to select cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a simple user form in Excel to enter the date that a staff member did a certain task. I have a spreadsheet that lists all of my staff down column B and I have a list of all the tasks along row 5.

I've created a form with a couple of combo boxes so I can select the staff member and also select the task. There is also a text box which I will type a date into.

What I need is when I click the "submit" button it will enter the date contained in the text box into the cell defined by the 2 selections in the combo boxes. If either of the combo boxes have nothing selected then no data should be entered into the spreadsheet when the button is clicked.

```
Dim nameRow As Integer 
Dim job1col As Integer 
nameRow = cbxStaffName.ListIndex + 6 
job1col = cbxJob1.ListIndex + 3 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Rotation").Cells(nameRow, job1col).Value = tbxDate.Value
```

The combo box containing the list of staff names is called `cbxStaffName`. The combobox containg the jobs is `cbxJob1`. The textbox containing the date I want to enter is named `tbxDate`.

The combo boxes have been populated with data that exists on the spreadsheet, simply names down the left and jobs along the top. If for example `Jim` did the job `welding` I want to select `Jim` from one combo box, select `welding` from the other box and when I click the button the date will go into that cell on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Please share what you have so far, what you want it to look like, and which part you're stuck on.

Comment: @ashleedawg  
  
Dim nameRow As Integer  
Dim job1col As Integer  
  
nameRow = cbxStaffName.ListIndex + 6  
job1col = cbxJob1.ListIndex + 3  
  
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Rotation").Cells(nameRow, job1col).Value = tbxdate.Value  
  
This is the sub I have made to run when the submit button is pressed. When it get to assigning the listindex to the variables I get an object required error. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Code goes in the question - you can edit to include it there.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Normally you woul [edit] your post when adding code or any other relevant information. (Comments are subject to deletion, and are just harder to read) I added it for you.  We're definitely going to need more information. What are the combo boxes called? What values do they contain?  etc

Comment: thanks for the guidance @ash, I've edited the post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need an `If` statement to check if both checkboxes have a value:

```
If cbxStaffName.Value <> vbNullString And cbxJob1.Value <> vbNullString Then
    'write into cell
Else
    MsgBox "Please select staff and job first"
End If
```

Alternatively you can check the `ListIndex` which should be `-1` if nothing was selected.

---

Note that I recommend to [always use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) especially when dealing with row counts. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: thanks @peh, I've changed them to Long but I'm still getting an object required error when it gets to the line where I set the variables. Have I missed something?

Comment: Are your comboboxes named correctly? In which line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: The names are definitely correct, error comes up when it gets to nameRow = cbxStaffName.ListIndex + 6

Comment: If that code is in a module you will need to specify the userform: `YourUserFormName.cbxStaffName.ListIndex`. The error means that your combobox was not found.